# Posting data from AngularJS with Express, Node and Rest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, restful-architecture

I am quite new to the javascript stack and have been trying to get a form post from angular onto to mongo. I am able to get a list back, but not able to post.

The below code lists ok, but when I post, it posts a blank record (and moreover, it keeps posting every couple of minutes even though I don't do any action on the page)

I can see that its able to call the Server side method, but the data is not being passed on towards persistence.

I know I am doing something stupid, but just not sure what it is. I've searched all over google, but don't see the solution which I can take. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
============jade================
    div(ng-app="sell" ng-controller="sellCtlr")
        .container-fluid
        form#listingForm.form-horizontal
                      .form-group
                       .row
                           .col-xs-8
                               label.control-label(for="title") title 
                               input#title.form-control(type="text", name="title", ng-model="listing.title")
                   .form-group
                       .row
                           .col-xs-8
                               label.control-label(for="subTitle") sub-title
                               input#subTitle.form-control(type="text", name="subTitle",, ng-model="listing.subTitle")

  .........
  .........
                        .form-group
                       .col-xs-6
                           button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit" ng-click="createListing()") Submit
============app.js================
/* server side controllers **/
var listController = require('./server/controllers/list-controller');

/* routes */
var sell = require('./client/routes/sell');

/* rest api */
app.get('/api/listings', listController.list);
app.post('/api/listings', listController.create);

/* sell route */
app.use('/sell', sell);

============sell.js (sell route)================
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET sell page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('sell', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* POST sell page. */
router.post('/api/listings', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('sell', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;

============sellCtlr.js (client side)================    

var app = angular.module('sell', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('sellCtlr', ['$scope', '$resource',
    function($scope, $resource){

    var Listing = $resource('/api/listings');
    $scope.listing = new Listing();

    $scope.createListing = function(){

        Listing.save($scope.listing, function(){
            //data saved. do something here.
        });//saves an entry. Assuming $scope.listing is the Listing object
        };
    }]);

============list-controller.js (server side)================

var Listing = require('../models/listing');

// save listing
module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var listing = new Listing(req.body);
  listing.save(function (err, result){
      res.json(result);
  });
}
//retrieve all listings
module.exports.list = function(req, res){
Listing.find({}, function(err, results) {
    res.json(results);
});
}


============listing.js (model, server side)================

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Listing', {
  title: String,
  subTitle: String

});
```

Many Thanks guys

EDIT 2 -- FULL app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/*%%%%% server side controllers %%%%%%**/
var listController = require('./server/controllers/list-controller');
/*%%%%% server side controllers %%%%%%**/


/*%%%%% mongoose config %%%%%%**/
var secrets = require('./config/secrets');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//Connect to the MongoDB
mongoose.connect(secrets.db);
/*%%%%% mongoose config %%%%%%**/

/*%%%%% routes %%%%%%**/
var index = require('./client/routes/index');
var listing = require('./client/routes/listing');
var users = require('./client/routes/users');
var sell = require('./client/routes/sell');
/*%%%%% routes %%%%%%**/

/*%%%%% express setup %%%%%%**/
var app = express();
/*%%%%% express setup %%%%%%**/

/*%%%%% view engine setup %%%%%%**/
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'client/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
/*%%%%% view engine setup %%%%%%**/

/*%%%%% client side directories %%%%%%**/
app.use(express.static('client'));
app.use(express.static('client/views'));

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/views/js'));

app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/client/views/css'));

/*%%%%% rest api's %%%%%%**/
app.get('/api/listings', listController.list);
app.post('/api/listings', listController.create);
/*%%%%% rest api's %%%%%%**/



// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/sell', sell);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't registering the model correctly, you need to use `mongoose.Schema`. I'm surprised you aren't getting an error.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Listing', new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  subTitle: String
}));
```

EDIT1:

Change your save() call to the following:

```
$scope.createListing = function(){
  $scope.listing.$save();
};
```

EDIT3

The order in which you register your middleware matters. You are registering your routes, before your bodyparser, this is not correct. Your body parser, and other middleware must be registered BEFORE the routes/API.

See below:

```
/*%%%%% express setup %%%%%%**/
var app = express();
/*%%%%% express setup %%%%%%**/

/*%%%%% view engine setup %%%%%%**/
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'client/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
/*%%%%% view engine setup %%%%%%**/

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// ***Register the API AFTER the body and cookie parser**

/*%%%%% client side directories %%%%%%**/
app.use(express.static('client'));
app.use(express.static('client/views'));

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/views/js'));

app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/client/views/css'));

/*%%%%% rest api's %%%%%%**/
app.get('/api/listings', listController.list);
app.post('/api/listings', listController.create);
/*%%%%% rest api's %%%%%%**/

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/sell', sell);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks @Yuri Zarubin, for offering help. I tried your correction but still the same result.  (creating ->  _id : ObjectId("55e5bd389855141c195033d7"), _v: 0). If I fill some data in the server side in list-controller.js, it persists. Im not sure why the post on the client side resource is not sending the data over to the server controller.

Comment: There is no error. Just pushes a blank record with the object id and no data(title and subtitle). Did a console.log on the list-controller.js and gives me (Server side list-controller *** create *** called....
listing object: { _id: 55e5bdb09855141c195033d8 }
title: undefined subtitle: undefined)

Comment: But a get request on the resource comes back with data from db with my original code.

Comment: Looks like your issue is that the values being sent to the server aren't correct. I've edited my answer, try that. try `console.log(req.body)` and post the results.

Comment: Tried that too, same result. (Server side list-controller *** create *** called....
request body: undefined
listing object: { _id: 55e5c4af57e379b81a571f15 }
title: undefined subtitle: undefined). Just to add that the client side $scope.listing contains the title and subtitle data from the form.

Comment: See my second edit. If your req.body is `undefined`, then that means your body isn't being parsed. Install a body parser middleware.

Comment: I guess i done that, full app.js file posted to my original post.

Comment: So here's the thing, the order in which you register your routes and middleware matters.  See my edit # 3

Comment: Working now @Yuri Zarubin, cant thank you enough. Thank you. Tried to give the score to your answer, but im ranked below. :-)